Why is tensor product used to model the early and late time excitations of a region of a two-side black hole?
In their paper
(Large $N$ algebras and generalized entropy), Witten et al. studied the excitations of the right side $R$ of a two-side black hole. They consider the algebra $\mathcal{A}_{R,0}$ generated by non-central single-trace operators $a(x, t)$ at an event $(x, t)$ and the auther one that is generated by non-central single-trace operators $a(x, t')$ at an event $(x', T+t')$, where $T$ is a parametrically large time gaps which separated the two algebras :

"Concretely, let $T = T(N)$ be a smooth function of $N$ such that $T(N) \to \infty$ in the $N \to \infty$ limit. For the moment, we shall assume that $T$ diverges less quickly than the scrambling time $t_{\text{scr}} = \frac{\beta}{2\pi} \log S_{\text{BH}}$, so that at large $N$ we have $t_{\text{scr}} \gg T \gg \beta$."

They come to the conclusion that in the large N limit and under the above asumptions, the families $(a_i(x_i, t_i))$ and $(b_j(x_j, t_j))$ are asymptotycally independence, $i.e.,$ per axample
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \langle a_1(x_1, t_1) b_2(x_2, T + t_2) a_3(x_3,t_3) b_4(x_4, T + t_4) \rangle_\beta = \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle a_1(x_1, t_1) a_3(x_3, t_3) \rangle_\beta \langle b_2(x_2, t_2) b_4(x_4, t_4) \rangle_\beta,$$
which means according them that the algebra  $\mathcal{C}_{R,0}$ generated by $\mathcal{A}_{R,0}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{R,0}$ is given by the tenso product of these two algebras, $i.e.,
\mathcal{C}_{R,0} \cong \mathcal{A}_{R,0} \otimes \mathcal{B}_{R,0}$ and the large $N$ hole Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{C}$ on which $\mathcal{C}_{R,0}$ acts is also the tensor product $\mathcal{H}_{C}=\mathcal{H}_{A} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{B}$ of the large $N$ Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_{A}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{A}$ on which $\mathcal{A}_{R,0}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{R,0}$ act.
Question: are the two regions of $R$ associated two the algebras $\mathcal{A}_{R,0}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{R,0}$ spatially separated? Does the split property operate in this situation in order to ensure the use of tensor product to model the independence subregions of $R$?
